# Mime Problems when hosting in AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

The script from “https://main.d2v33zbtn1rc1d.amplifyapp.com/static/js/main.39057085.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
shop
The stylesheet https://main.d2v33zbtn1rc1d.amplifyapp.com/static/css/main.ab4295b4.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". shop
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

im getting these error for a react project and i have no clue how to fix them at all

I tried changing the rewrite headers but that didnt work.